# How can I delete a bucket in Google Cloud Platform from java?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform

Consider the below code which allows me to create a bucket from Java...

```
package com.lscale.gcp.test1;

import com.google.cloud.storage.Bucket;
import com.google.cloud.storage.BucketInfo;
import com.google.cloud.storage.Storage;
import com.google.cloud.storage.StorageOptions;

public class CreateBucket {
    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        // Instantiates a client
        Storage storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();

        // The name for the new bucket
        String bucketName = Properties.bucketId;  // "my-new-bucket";

        // Creates the new bucket
        Bucket bucket = storage.create(BucketInfo.of(bucketName));

        System.out.printf("Bucket %s created.%n", bucket.getName());
    }
}
```

The question is: how can I delete it, using java code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the bucket must be empty.

Then you can do:

storage.buckets().delete(Properties.bucketId).execute()

where storage is com.google.api.services.storage

I hope it helps! :)